# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions incremental UIImage read / draw / write to PNG

Tags: objective-c

During first launch of the app I want to show UIImage. After 2 seconds I have to write it to file. Each next launch of the app, I have to read the file and draw it on the screen and then each 1 second, I have to draw UIBezierPath of 5 random points over it. When the app closes, the latest version of the UIImage with all UIBezierPaths renderings, have to be written to the file.

I would like to use code like this:

```
UIImage *imageSrc = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile];
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[imageSrc drawInRect:];
[UIBezierPath fill]; // bezier path with 5 points
UIImage *imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *dataNew = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageNew);
[dataNew writeToFile: atomically:YES];
```

My question : UIImagePNGRepresentation  is Lossless ? After 500 repeats can I observe quality lose ? Maybe better is to use CGBitmapContext ?

Comment: did u look into this https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ ?

Comment: Interesting but it doesn't respond to my questions directly. Is UIImagePNGRepresentation lossless or not ? Is UIImagePNGRepresentation equal to bitmap ?

Comment: as far as i know, PNGRepresentation is lossless.